# How to upload an image to the ASP.NET CORE WEB API in BYTE ARRAY format using React JS, 400 bad request

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

We are trying to send some data to the ASP.NET CORE WEB API server and upload that data to a website using axios post request in React and the main problem is in sending image in BYTE ARRAY format to a server. Server accepts images only in BYTE ARRAY format. It gives us an error POST 400. Upload.jsx:47 Error: Request failed with status code 400. Please help. Here is the our code using react hooks:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Upload = () => {
  const [upload, setUpload] = useState({
    ruName: "",
    azName: "",
    kaName: "",
    enName: "",
    image: null,
    shopId: localStorage.getItem("shopId")
  });

  const changeHandler = e => {
    setUpload({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const uploadHandler = async e => {
    const base64 = await convertBase64(e.target.files[0]);
    setUpload({ image: base64 });
  };

  const convertBase64 = file => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

      fileReader.onload = () => {
        resolve(fileReader.result);
      };

      fileReader.onerror = error => {
        reject(error);
      };
    });
  };

  const onAddCategory = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        "https://midamoapi.ge/api/productcategories/",
        upload
      );
      console.log(res);

    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  console.log(upload);

  return (
    <div className="container-add">
      <input name="ruName" onChange={changeHandler} type="text" />
      <input name="azName" onChange={changeHandler} type="text" />
      <input name="enName" onChange={changeHandler} type="text" />
      <input name="kaName" onChange={changeHandler} type="text" />
      <input name="image" type="file" onChange={uploadHandler} />
      <button className="btn" onClick={onAddCategory}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Upload;
```

Comment: Hi @GreatData, any updates about this case? If the reply did help resolve the problem, you can [accept it as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

> Request failed with status code 400

In your code, we can find that you use `FileReader.readAsDataURL()` to get a base64 encoded string of the selected image, then post the data to your action method.

Please check if your action method and accepted parameter look like below.

*Category class*

```
public class Category
{
    public string RuName { get; set; }
    public string AzName { get; set; }
    public string EnName { get; set; }
    public string KaName { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }  //please note that Image property is string type
    public int ShopId { get; set; }
}
```

*Action method*

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddCategory(Category category)
{
    //...
    //your code logic here
```

Test Result

[image]

Besides, if you'd like to process or save the image file using `IFormFile`, you can try to pass the data via `FormData` rather than in json format data through request body.